# Switch to a different cpu thread in gdb

Tags: gdb

First timer here. 
While doing gdb and getting prdasummary, I know to find the panicked cpu by looking at inPanic, I also find other cpu running one process which I want to find its locals.

Can I switch to a different cpu and see its registers?

Thanks,
zXi

Comment: you mean gdb's thread command or something different?

Comment: Yes.. Pretty much command like `thread apply all bt`. However, I need to parse through tons of threads to find out the correct cpu and its registers. Is there any other easier method to switch to the cpu directly and get its info

Comment: Stack and registers state is local to thread. Even if you nave 100 threads, they could be running on single CPU core if you want to (ofc. if you haven't done anything special for it - kernel will try to balance it). So basically you're still always reading it from threads. What do you want, dump them all into text?

Comment: Dumping into text would be easier by set logging options. Here is my dilemma currently.. 1. prdasummary shows list of processors and the processor in panic. 2. bt of the dump shows list of functions, address, arguments, blah, blah.. pertaining to one function which has panicked, [Let us say CopyFromDisk]. 3. The bt also shows one function [say CheckNic] which is NOT related AT ALL to the current bt. This is also good. 4. BUT the address region pointed out by the CheckNic is the address seen in CopyFromDisk..

Comment: In prdasummary, of 8processors, the panicked was 3rd and the CheckNic was running in 7th processor. So I wanted to find out if we can switch to the 7th processor instance and check for memory corruption or rank violation